# Apple Tv (2nd Generation) post update

Tags: appletv

I just got an apple tv (the black box). I was prompted to update and so I did. When completed, the only thing that would come on screen is the large blue iTunes icon and a white cable pointing to it from below. I am assuming it is asking to connect to itunes? Not sure what to do! do I need to but the cable?

oh to note that I watched videos on it before the update (so I did set up my account and all).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your update failed for some reason. You're correct, the icon you're seeing on screen means that you need to connect it to iTunes. You need a micro USB cable to do this.

What happens if you plug it into iTunes?

Comment: well @Amy, i am seriously pissed at apple for not supplying the cable in the package! just bought one and the result was a no version ios on the apple tv. so restoring now and hoping this works.

Comment: It's a rare thing to see an update fail on an Apple TV, the USB is there to enable support for things like this, but in the ideal world and for almost all users of the Apple TV it would remain in the box unused.  Most people have a mini one kicking around, I must have 2 dozen for everything from other phones, PS3 controllers, headset chargers, external drive cables etc etc etc.

Comment: An alternative to purchasing a cable is to make an appointment at the Apple Store Genius Bar. As @stuffe says, failures are not a common occurrence.